Black Border Appears at the Top of ScrollView in React Native App on macOS Using Mac Catalyst
I'm encountering an issue with my React Native application when running it on macOS using Mac Catalyst. A black border appears at the top of the ScrollView. I have tried various approaches to remove it but none have worked so far.
Screenshot:

My Code:
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';

import { IProps } from './types';

export const ScrollViewComponent: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {
  const { children, contentContainerStyle } = props;

  return <ScrollView>{children}</ScrollView>;
};


Steps I’ve Taken:

Tried setting borderWidth: 0 and borderColor: 'transparent' in the ScrollView styles.
Used Platform.OS to apply macOS-specific styles.
Checked parent components for unintended styles.
Ensured my React Native and relevant dependencies are up to date.



Are you try this borderTopWidth: 0 and borderWidth: 0

Yes, I've tried. And also if I try to add some border it adds below the black border

I think Then It is width of your Top Tabs. Are you using Material Top Tabs Navigator ?

The tabs are just views. I tried creating a new empty project with React Native and encountered the same issue. I only added a ScrollView with some heights, and the black border appears in the ScrollView when running on Mac Catalyst.
